# Unable to enlarge a picture

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to enlarge a smaller picture. I have a small and a large version of the pictures. I've searched on the internet, the one i'm using is the best i've found.

I know this would be much easier with 'Lightbox2' or other javascript things, but the purpose is to only use html & css.

Here you can find the link (dropbox, .zip file) to the  website' folder --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61634717/Website.zip

It would be nice if someone could find the problem why my smaller pictures aren't enlarged when hovering over. The website is only showing the small pictures when hovering over them.

Here is the html code (for one picture):

```
<div class="ienlarger"><a href="#nogo"><img src="Pictures/Artists/PeopleTalkTechnoSmall.png" alt="thumb" class="resize_thumb" /><span>
 <img src="Pictures/Artists/PeopleTalkTechno-Large.png" alt="large" /><br />Some text can go here.</span></a>
</div>
```

Here is the css code:

```
.ienlarger {
float: left;
clear: none;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.ienlarger a { 
display:block;
text-decoration: none;
cursor:default;
}

.ienlarger a:hover{
position:relative;
}

.ienlarger span img {
border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.ienlarger a span {
position: absolute;
display:none;
color: #FFCC00;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
font-weight: bold;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 13px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.ienlarger img {
border-width: 0;
}

.ienlarger a:hover span { 
display:inline-table;
top: 50px;
left: 90px;
z-index: 100;
}

.resize_thumb {
width: 170px;
height : auto;
}
```

NOTE: Do not pay attention to the background colors :D. I know they are weird, but it is just for me to see the different < div > (they will be changed when the website is closer to being completed).

Comment: Perhaps you could post some relevant code here so we don't need to go to the trouble of downloading your website. Putting more effort into questions often yields better answers.

Comment: Could you please put an example of your problem in jsfiddle or somewhere like that? Cuz here is not somewhere to put a big zipped project to debug.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code in the question instead of linking to a zip file containing your website? This way, the question becomes self-reliant. It also makes it easier for others to help you, and as a side effect makes others more *willing* to help you, since we don't have to go through so much extra code.

Comment: I will try to add the relevant code, it is big. That's why I didn't want to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I downloaded your code and messed around with it.

Removing `max-width: 100%;` from the `img` CSS seems to have fixed it (line 25). In the future, please post the code along with your question, or if there are a lot of parts to it, a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is also acceptable.

Thanks.

Comment: Ty so much for the double help you gave me. That change is working pretty good.
I will use a 'JSFiddle' next time, had no idea how I could share these lines of code.
Realy thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I understand how it is when there's a lot of code that plays into the thing you're talking about. Anyway you know what to do now, so all is well. Good luck with your website. :)

Comment: Yea a lot of code, I'm not so good with html & css. Still learning all sort of things.
Ty so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your css you have all images set to a max-width of 100% probably to make it responsive, which is good. But that is also your problem. The images can only be 100% of their container and no bigger. If you remove img {max-width: 100%} from your css that fixes your issue.

But is also makes it not repsonsive. :-(

So your solution is to add a `class="larger"` to the bigger image and add another line to your css. You would end up with something like this:

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
img.larger {
    max-width: 500px; /* the maximum size you would allow for larger images */
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get to the point that the whole website is responsive to the size of the window it is in. I'm not good with all the 'classes' & 'id's'. I understand your solution, but I can't figure it out so it fits (and works) with my html/css.

Comment: Adding the class would look something like this...                    `<img class="larger" src="Pictures/Artists/PeopleTalkTechno-Large.png" alt="large" />`